# How to resize image to browser screen

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

Hi I working on simple image resize to only in html/css (no js) especially for mobile devices.

I want to limit the maximum height and width to 100% and not deform the image.
I created a simple checkbox-based zooming, but the element must have position: absolute, and that is a problem for other elements (it's covered).

Everything seems at first glance that works.. but the container for the image has a fixed height from the top as well as elements p, and that's the problem.

Please check te code :

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xred3rs6/6/)

Simple HTML

```
<p>some text...</p>
<input id="zoom" type="checkbox">
<label for="zoom" class="container">
  <img alt="kitten" src="http://placekitten.com/g/600/300"/>
</label>
<p>some another text</p>
```

The CSS

```
* {
  margin:0 auto;
}
html, body{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  text-align:justify;
}
p{
  display:block;
  height:25%;
  overflow:hidden;
}
label + p {
  position:absolute;
  top:260px;
  height:auto;
}
#zoom{
  display:none;
}
input + .container {
  position:absolute;
  z-index:9999;
  top:25%;
  right:0;
  left:0;
  bottom:0;
  width:300px;
  height:150px;
  text-align:center;
  cursor:pointer;
  display:block;
  -webkit-transition: height .4s, width .4s, background-color .4s, top .4s;
  transition: height .4s, width .4s, background-color .4s, top .4s;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0)
}
input:checked + .container {
  position:fixed;
  top:0%;
  right:0;
  left:0;
  bottom:0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}
input + .container img{
  max-width: 100% !important;
  max-height: 100% !important;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

Comment: Try removing the position:absolute and width from input + .container. It will make image responsive

Comment: In that case, the image while zooming behaving strangely.. :/

Comment: Did you try giving the width:100% in input + .container?

Comment: I do not, I want to fill the image is always either 100%, height or width.
Always an image to see the entire (contain).
The problem is that if I have absolute position affects other elements.
And if there is not a smooth transition.

Comment: Have a look into Media Queries. They're great for ironing out problems with resizing.

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the `width: 300px` from input + .container

Please check te code :[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xred3rs6/7/)

Answer (score 1):

Check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xred3rs6/13/), I've added extra container and perfomed some css manipulations, also added more text around to test correct behavior of image

```
<label for="zoom" class="container">
    <div class="shadowbox">
        <img alt="kitten" src="http://placekitten.com/g/600/300"/>
    </div>
</label>
```

Comment: This is clever! But try scroll to top or down (image top or down) and click on image - effect starts from the center, not from the picture.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

[JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/5owada3f/)

**HTML:**

```
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. In dapibus augue non sapien. Aliquam id dolor. Nulla quis diam.Praesent dapibus. Nullam at arcu a est sollicitudin euismod.</p>
<div class="layer">
<input id="zoom" type="checkbox">
<label for="zoom" class="container">
   <img alt="kitten" src="http://placekitten.com/g/600/300"/> 
</label>
</div>
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. In dapibus augue non sapien. Aliquam id dolor. Nulla quis diam. Praesent dapibus. Nullam at arcu a est sollicitudin euismod. Curabitur vitae diam non enim vestibulum interdum. Sed ac dolor sit amet purus malesuada congue. Suspendisse nisl. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Nullam lectus justo, vulputate eget mollis sed, tempor sed magna. Pellentesque arcu. Nunc auctor. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Mauris tincidunt sem sed arcu. Pellentesque ipsum. Nulla turpis magna, cursus sit amet, suscipit a, interdum id, felis. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Vestibulum erat nulla, ullamcorper nec, rutrum non, nonummy ac, erat.
</p>
```

**CSS**

```
* {
margin:0 auto;
}
html, body{
width:100%;
height:100%;
text-align:justify;
}
p{
padding: 5px;
display:block
overflow:hidden;
}
label + p {
position:absolute;
height:auto;
}
#zoom{
display:none;
}
.layer{
display: inline-block; float: left; position: relative;
}
input + .container {
top: 0%;
left: 0;
z-index:9999;
cursor:pointer;
width: 300px;
height: 150px;
display:block;
-webkit-transition: height .4s, width .4s, background-color .4s, top .4s;
transition: height .4s, width .4s, background-color .4s, top .4s;
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0)
}
input:checked + .container {
position:fixed;
top:0%;
right: 0;
left:0;
bottom: 0;
width:100%;
height:100%;
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}
input:checked + .container img{
height: 100%; width: 100%;
}
input + .container img{
max-width: 100% !important;
max-height: 100% !important;
position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```